# Registered custom element is undefined

Tags: javascript, custom-element

I've decided to look into [custom elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements), but i can't seem to get any of the examples to work.

Take for example:

```js
window.customElements.whenDefined('file-bag')
    .then(() => console.log('Registered'))
    .then(() => console.log(window.customElements.get('file-bag')))
    .catch(console.error);
window.customElements.define('file-bag', class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    var shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
    shadowRoot.innerHTML = `<strong>Shadow dom super powers for the win!</strong>`;
  }
});
```

```html
<file-bag></file-bag>
```

*Src: [https://auth0.com/blog/web-components-how-to-craft-your-own-custom-components/](https://auth0.com/blog/web-components-how-to-craft-your-own-custom-components/_)*

The expeced result is:

```
<file-bag>
  <strong>Shadow dom super powers for the win!</strong>
</file-bag>
```

But its not working.
The element is being registered, however `customElements.get('file-bag')` returns `undefined`.
What am i missing?

I'm on Chrome 70.

**Edit:**

Looks like its a problem with the way I'm loading the script.
Having the script inline works:

```
<script>
    window.customElements.whenDefined('file-bag')
        .then(() => console.log('Registered'))
        .then(() => console.log(window.customElements.get('file-bag')))
        .catch(console.error);
    window.customElements.define('file-bag', class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        var shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
        shadowRoot.innerHTML = `<strong>Shadow dom super powers for the win!</strong>`;
    }
    });
</script>
<file-bag></file-bag>
```

But having it in a separate file doesn't.

```
<script src="./index.js"></script>
<file-bag></file-bag>
```

Comment: Testing it on Chrome 70 and works fine for me.

Comment: Having it in a separate script also works fine for me: https://khrismuc.github.io/

Comment: @ChrisG What os are you on?

Comment: Windows 7. Also works in Firefox btw.

Answer (score 2):

One thing to note is that you do not need to use `window` for all the `customElements` calls.

I modified your code below and it runs fine embedded, like you said.

```js
customElements.whenDefined('file-bag')
  .then(() => console.log('Registered'))
  .then(() => console.log(customElements.get('file-bag')))
  .catch(console.error);
        
        
customElements.define('file-bag', class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    var shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
    shadowRoot.innerHTML = `<strong>Shadow dom super powers for the win!</strong>`;
  }
});
```

```html
<file-bag></file-bag>
```

I also created two files, `FileBag.js`:

```
customElements.whenDefined('file-bag')
  .then(() => console.log('Registered'))
  .then(() => console.log(customElements.get('file-bag')))
  .catch(console.error);


customElements.define('file-bag', class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    var shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
    shadowRoot.innerHTML = `<strong>Shadow dom super powers for the win!</strong>`;
  }
});
```

and `FileBagExample.html`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Simple Tag</title>
  <script src="FileBag.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <file-bag></file-bag>
</body>
</html>
```

And it works fine for me in Chrome 70 and Firefox 63.

> Yes, Firefox 63 now supports Web Components. <strike>We only wait on Edge. for 100% support.</strike>
>
> **All major browsers now support Custom Elements and Shadow DOM.**